# Compiler gives "function not declared in this scope" but function was declared (C++)

Tags: c++

In the following C++ code I get a "lookup_add_anim was not declared in this scope" error when I call `lookup_add_anim`, but the function was already declared:

```
void loopup_add_anim(Setting& setting,AnimList& animlist){
    bool loop;
    loop = setting["loop"];
    Setting& frames = setting["frames"];
    Anim anim = new Anim(loop);
    for(int i=0;i<frames.getLength();i++){
        anim.addFrame(frames[i]);
    }
    animlist.addAnim(anim);
}

void set_anims(Config* plaanims,AnimList& animlist){
    const Setting& root = plaanims->getRoot();
    try{
        loopup_add_anim(root["stand_top"],animlist);
        lookup_add_anim(root["aim_up"],animlist);
        lookup_add_anim(root["stand_bottom"],animlist);
        lookup_add_anim(root["running"],animlist);
        lookup_add_anim(root["jumping"],animlist);
    }catch(const SettingNotFoundException &nfex){
        cerr << "Setting not found at" << nfex.getPath() << endl;
    }
}
```

I have no clue what is going on. Please can anyone give any pointers?

Comment: what is the type of `root["stand_top"]`?

Comment: `Anim anim = new Anim(loop);` This is wrong. It should be `Anim anim(loop);`

Comment: You are not providing the full error.  Functions in C++ can be overloaded, so the error message should have listed the parameter types along with the function name.

Comment: In the declaration, you have written `loopup`, and you are calling `lookup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It's probably just a typo in your question*, but the function you're calling is named `lookup_add_anim` but the function you're declaring is named `loopup_add_anim`.